# C# const vs lambda efficiency

Tags: c#, lambda, constants

I have some libraries that contain a large number of constants. Any application that uses the library will use some or none of those constants. So, I was wondering whether using lambda expressions  (for example):

```
public static Milliseconds {
    public static int OneSecond => 1000;
    public static int TwoSeconds => 2000;
    .
    .
}
```

would be more efficient either in terms of file sizes (exe or dll) or run-time speed than:

```
public static Milliseconds {
    public const int OneSecond = 1000;
    public const int TwoSeconds = 2000;
    .
    .
}
```

I'm sure any differences would be minimal. I'm not looking to squeeze the last byte or nano-second out, I'm just curious. Thank you.

Comment: Try it out.....

Comment: Have you tried to **measure** it?

Comment: This sounds like something that you're in a better position to test than anyone else. Are applications likely to use these in tight loops? If so, have you tested what the impact is? Are they likely to want to use those constants in *other* constant expressions? Also note that your code doesn't contain any lambda expressions. It contains expression-bodied properties. There are no delegates or expression trees involved.

Comment: I guess the getter properties are likely to be inlined. But even so, semantically, `const` seems to fit better?

Comment: Should you really be letting people who can't calculate the number of milliseconds in 2 seconds do programming?

Comment: Constants in C# are **propagated** by the compiler. If you change your `const` values then any consuming libraries will need to be recompiled also. From the context of your values this looks like it would be unlikely for you but it's something that has caught me out in the past.

Comment: But because the constant value is propagated, the compiler will actually insert the constant value into the consuming library's code, so `const` will be faster at run time because the calling library won't even go into your assembly afaik.

Comment: Constants get resolved at compile time and does not get added to the executable file.  Also if the constant is used multiple numbers of times in program the optimizer may use same expression to reduce file size.  Static variables will use more executable memory and use the same file size as a constant.

Comment: For fundamental constant values (e.g. SecondsPerMinute, FeetPerMile and so on) you should just use actual constants. For "constants" that may conceivably change (e.g. MaxBufferSize) you should use properties (or possibly public readonly fields in some cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property approach actually creates methods like `get_OneSecond()` which return a number which is stored in your assembly.

The second const approach does not create any members, it **inlines the value** of your constants wherever you use it at compile-time.

So, approach 1 will take more space and will be less "efficient", i.e. require more instructions to be executed. Of course, we talk about unnoticeable and tiny differences.

However, at the same time approach 1 gives you two things:

- It gives more flexibility allowing you to encapsulate your logic. For example, one day you can make `OneSecond` be acquired another way (loaded from configuration / calculated / etc.) instead of being constant. These changes will not change abstraction and affect someone who use your `Milliseconds` class.
- It lets you update your values by replacing DLL. If you use constants and replace the DLL which contains your `Milliseconds` class, it won't work, since constants are inlined - you will have to rebuild the whole project.

Comment: `public static readonly int OneSecond = 1000;` (`readonly` instead of `const`) is more *readable* then approach 1 when we want flexibility

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you! Yes, it looks more appropriate in case if you we are sure that this value is unmodifiable. If there is a chance, that someday we will need to calculate its value on each getter access or according to some external values (like current thread ID or authenticated user name etc.), then use property.

Answer (score 1):

In response to one of the comments I received, I have now bench-marked this. I had assumed that the compiler would be able to inline and optimise a lambda expression so in this case the two would be virtually the same, but it turns out I was wrong.

My benchmark just confirms the answer from Yeldar Kurmangaliyev. Using lambda expressions in place of constants both increases the size of the dll that they are in and the size of the final exe, as well as having a detrimental affect of performance. This is true for both debug and release builds.

My benchmark used 4,500 constants or lambda expressions, constructing an array from them and then did some simple maths on the array and then repeated the process a hundred thousand times.

Using consts:

> dll size was 94kb
>
> exe size was 22kb
>
> benchmark took 2 seconds.

Using lambdas:

> dll size was 173kb
>
> exe size was 115kb
>
> benchamrk took 17 seconds.

Timings for both were improved running release over debug (0.6 seconds and 9.5 seconds). Your figures may vary, I've only included mine as a guide.

So, I'll stick with `const` for constants.